# SQL query having count and group by taking longer to execute on multiple parallel run

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, parallel-processing

My application is running a query to generate a pie chart. The query is a group by statement having multiple joins and `count(*)` function. UI has a run button which runs the query and generates pie chart on UI using query data.

On a single run, the query is taking ~6 seconds. On running it 2 times in quick successions, the execution time almost doubles (~12 seconds). It is observed that the query time is multiple of the no. of parallel runs. The issue is with this query only as other queries without group by works perfectly.

Note that the on parallel runs, each execution of the query is taking almost same time(which multiples of runs).

Is this an issue with Oracle DB configuration?

```html
<TABLE class="TreeTableWidget" border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100% bgcolor=#efefef><tr><td> 

 <!-- ..........................data begin...........................  -->

    <TABLE class=TreeTableWidget border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 align=center width=100%"  bgcolor=#ffffff> 
    <tr class="TableCell">

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OPERATION</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#aaaaaa>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OBJECT_NAME</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>OPTIONS</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#aaaaaa>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>CARDINALITY</font>&nbsp;</td>

       <td valign=top bgcolor=#bbbbbb>&nbsp;<font color=#444477>COST</font>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;SELECT STATEMENT&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;77&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;28255&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/gray.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;HASH&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;</td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;GROUP BY&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffdf >&nbsp;77&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffd2 >&nbsp;28255&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff ><font size=-1><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/table.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%>&nbsp;TABLE ACCESS&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;LCSSAMPLE&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;FULL&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfdfdf >&nbsp;608891&nbsp;</font></td>
      <td width=11% valign=top bgcolor=#dfd5d1 >&nbsp;28240&nbsp;</font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(119,119,0)>&nbsp;Other XML&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,0,102)>&nbsp;{info}&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;info type="has_user_tab"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;yes&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;info type="db_version"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;19.0.0.0&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;info type="parse_schema"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;"TEST01"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;info type="plan_hash_full"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;3197009832&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;info type="plan_hash"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;3739428270&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;info type="plan_hash_2"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;3197009832&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;stats type="compilation"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;stat name="bg"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;0&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,102,0)>&nbsp;q o="2" f="y"&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,0,102)>&nbsp;{n}&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;SEL$1&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,0,102)>&nbsp;{t}&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;LCSSAMPLE&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;SEL$1&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(136,0,102)>&nbsp;{hint}&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;USE_HASH_AGGREGATION(@"SEL$1")&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;FULL(@"SEL$1" "LCSSAMPLE"@"SEL$1")&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;ALL_ROWS&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;DB_VERSION('19.1.0')&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('18.1.0')&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td width=45% valign=top bgcolor=#ffffff colspan=5><table width=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td width=1%><table CELLSPACING=0 cellpadding=0><tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><IMG SRC="images/minus.gif" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0><IMG SRC="images/empty.png" wWIDTH=16 hHEIGHT=16 BORDER=0></td><tr></table></td>  <td width=99%><font color=rgb(102,136,0)>&nbsp;IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS&nbsp;</td></tr></table></font></td>
   </tr>
</table>

 <!-- ..........................data end...........................  -->

</td></tr></TABLE>
```

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLANs for the query when it runs fast and when it runs slowly

Comment: It's important to remove you application code from the mix. Have it log the SQL it is running, then take that SQL and run it manually in a database client directly against the database. Test it that way. If it performs poorly, generate an execution plan and share both it and the SQL itself in your question, without which nobody can really help.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, it may be an issue with Oracle database configuration. I have experienced the same in the past once.

Try reviewing the configuration settings, such as memory allocation, parallelism, and resource limits.Set those in such a way those can match to your problem case and can optimize the performance.

Comment: As I am not a DBA, can you point out any specific DB configurations settings?